# Текст от третьего лица: допустимость отхода от "ведущего (обзорного) персонажа"

Tags: литература, литературоведение

Попытаюсь описать всё максимально подробно, чтобы меня хотя бы поняли. Допустим, есть следующий отрывок текста:

> *Аня подбежала к гуляющим в парке родителям и сразу же принялась озадачивать их своим пожеланием:*
>
> *- Я хочу лошадку!*
>
> *Родители девочки переглянулись, пытаясь понять, где же их пятилетняя дочь успела увидеть лошадей. В их городе этих животных никто не
>   держит.*
>
> *- Я буду плести ей косички! - продолжала Аня, совершенно не обращая внимания на недоуменные взгляды родителей.*
>
> *Женщина шепотом спросила мужа, не позволял ли он дочери смотреть телевизор, на что мужчина лишь покачал головой.*
>
> *А Аня была в своих мыслях, где плела единорогу из азбуки косичку из его розовой гривы. Почему-то лошадка в мечтаниях девочки была ростом с
>   неё саму.*
>
> *Родители, которые всё ломали голову, как отговорить дочь от
>   огромного животного, Аню не волновали, а потому девочка на них даже не 
>   смотрела - она была уверена, что лошадку ей обязательно купят.*

Всё ли верно в данном отрывке? У меня уже был один вопрос по поводу того, как нужно писать в третьем лице, какую брать точку зрения. Тут, например, "обзорный" персонаж (персонаж, в чью голову влезает автор и чьи мысли описывает) - девочка Аня, но при этом описываются и действия её родителей, которые сама девочка не видит (точнее не обращает внимания, потому как ей всё равно). Аня не слышит шепот родителей, не видит их "недоуменные взгляды", тем не менее, это всё-таки описывается. Правильно ли данное? И насколько вообще можно выходить за рамки "обзорного" персонажа и описывать то, что он не видит/слышит/чувствует?

Вполне возможно, что я вовсе что-то не знаю по поводу написания текста в третьем лице. В любом случае я буду рада ссылкам на полезные статьи об этой теме и разъяснениям. Помогите мне, пожалуйста, разобраться в том, в чём я запуталась.

Собственно, вопросов именно на литературную тематику на этом сайте нет, а тег "литература" на вопроснике по русскому имеется. Если так судить, то всё по правилам, мной ничего не нарушено.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, здесь нет никакого "обзорного персонажа", рассказ ведётся от имени автора.Здесь же не всё даётся её глазами.  Автор описывает и мысли девочки, и чувства родителей.

Всё нормально. Если бы это было от имени девочки, было бы от первого лица, от лица героя. А так - во власти автора "влезть" в мысли и чувства своих героев.